# how jvm know the creation of servlet object

Tags: servlets

I have one webapplciation, i deployed it in server,server uses Jvm.
How jvm know the whether servelt object is created or not?
and one more thing In my web application having more than 5 servlet classes,then how jvm know which servlet instance created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Servlets are declared in web.xml, when an application server which is in compliance with Servlet API start, it try to look for this file. In web.xml you have listed the servlet you want to load and the classes you should load in order to start servlets.

Servlets has their own lifecycle, if application server can not start a servlet, exception could be thrown then application server know that the servlet is no available.

Try to read more about servlets there many good tutorial over the net.